# C#: List All Classes in Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, class-structure

I'd like to output (programmatically - C#) a list of all classes in my assembly.

Any hints or sample code how to do this? Reflection?

Comment: If your intention is to examine an assembly that is not referenced by your project, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Use [`Assembly.GetTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx). For example:

```
Assembly mscorlib = typeof(string).Assembly;
foreach (Type type in mscorlib.GetTypes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions for large assemblies? When I run this code for a 13.8 MB assembly my VS instance hangs for what feels like indefinitely. I tried a small 9 KB assembly and it worked just fine. I know what you are thinking - why do you have a 13.8 MB assembly - it is part of my data layer generated using a NetTeirs template. We have many tables.

Comment: @dyslexicanaboko: Well if you have lots of types, it will take a long time to enumerate them all. How many types *are* in your assembly though? And what are you doing with them? (Are you sure the problem is in extracting the types, or just what you're doing afterwards?)

Comment: I can't get past the asm.GetTypes() call, it just hangs - I mean it is obviously the fact that there are a lot of Types - I can't do anything because it is drilling away at trying to get them all. My CPU shoots to 30% on one of my 4 cores. I mean really I am just wondering if there is a way to say, "Hey - only look in THIS namespace" - I am under the impression that it's not possible because the GetTypes() method only has an empty constructor. I am trying to make an object browser of sorts.

Comment: @dyslexicanaboko: I'm afraid I don't know of any more efficient way of finding the types. Can you open it in Reflector or something similar?

Comment: Good point, I haven't tried that yet. My work around for now is to just target the classes directly using asm.GetType(fullyQualifiedClassName) - that works, but showing a list of classes to the user is not possible, which is what I wanted. This isn't client facing btw, I am using it internally for myself and other developers.

Comment: Doesn't this also include interfaces?

Comment: @DebugErr: Yes - it's easy enough to make it *just* classes if you want, but my guess is that the OP probably *really* wanted all the types.

Comment: for .NET Core it should be typeof(string).GetTypeInfo().Assembly

Comment: Since OP expressed a desire to list all _classes_ in an assembly, it's worth noting that `GetTypes()` will return **ALL** types - not simply classes, but also interfaces, enums, etc. If you just want classes, you can use a Linq extension method to filter like so: `MyAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass)`

Answer (score 115):

I'd just like to add to Jon's example. To get a reference to your own assembly, you can use:

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

`System.Reflection` namespace.

If you want to examine an assembly that you have no reference to, you can use either of these:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(fullAssemblyName);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fileName);
```

If you intend to instantiate your type once you've found it:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(fullAssemblyName);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
```

See the [Assembly class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx) for more information.

Once you have the reference to the `Assembly` object, you can use `assembly.GetTypes()` like Jon already demonstrated.

Comment: How could I reference a completely different assembly that is in my solution?

Comment: The easiest way is to use `typeof` with a type you know is in that assembly, and then the `Assembly` property, as in my example.

Comment: If you want to reference an assembly, say abc.dll, that is in your solution and if you are ok hardcoding the dll name, another approach to referencing the assembly is:   ` Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("abc");`

Comment: It loads only current assembly. I have a application or exe using 4 dlls or projects. How can i get names of the classes of those dlls?

Comment: @JonSkeet How would this be achievable in a "modern" c# environment? Such as when doing UWP development.

 UWP doesn't have the GetExecutingAssembly() method.

Comment: @DanielArmstrong: See my comment above... if you know any type in the assembly, just obtain the assembly from that.

Comment: all assemblies within solution can be access from here AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()