# Getting All Classe names in a project

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: List All Classes in Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315665/c-list-all-classes-in-assembly)

How I can get all class names in specific project using reflection?

---

### Edit 1)

Is it possible to distinguish between programmer defined class and built-in classes?

Comment: @Heinzi Right if we consider a project to be an assembly (something that normally is)

Comment: @xanatos: Of course. Since reflection can only be applied to assemblies and not to projects, I assumed that this is what Nima meant.

Comment: @Heinzi There is a good chance the OP didn't know this. I think it was important enough to point it out

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish between programmer defined class and built-in classes?

Comment: @Nima: I suggest you start a different SO question for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two previous posters are correct. However, if you wanted a list of all referenced assemblies and their types, you could do:

```
var referencedAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
var referencedTypes = referencedAssemblies.SelectMany(x => Assembly.Load(x.FullName).GetTypes());
```

This would give a list of all Types from the core libraries, third-parties etc which are referenced and *used*, if you are not using an assembly but have it referenced it wouldn't list its types.

It isn't greatly useful as it lists thousands of types from System and System.Core etc, but i'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, so it may be a start.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()` to get all types in the assembly that contains this line of code; the `Type` class has the `Name` property.

Answer (score 0):

use `Assembly.GetTypes`method