# How to get type of the custom UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got some custom WPF `UserControl`.

And it has implementation like this one

```
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl, IMyPluginInterface
```

How do I can get a type of that UserControl in other application?

Or how to enumerate types in assembly?

Thank you!

Comment: `typeof(CustomControl)`?

Comment: @voroninp I have to load it like an assembly I cannot do it.

Comment: If you load assembly dynamically you can search the type by its name: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx

Comment: Enumerate types in assembly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315665/c-list-all-classes-in-assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Type myType = myCustomUserControl.GetType();
```