# Validating the Workflow in Design Time

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

At the beginning, let me confess that I am totally new to Workflow Foundation. I am trying to write one custom activity, let's say we call it GoTo. This activity has a property called TargetActivityName (of type string). The TargetActivityName specifies the name (or DisplayName) of another activity present in the workflow. Now, I need to validate that the activity name is valid, that is, whenever the someone designs a workflow with the GoTo activity and specifies the TargetActivityName, the workflow should validate that an activity of that name is present.

Any ways to achieve this? I am not rehosting it, just using Visual Studio.

Thanks,

Jeevan

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the activities present in a assembly you can check 
[C#: List All Classes in Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315665/c-list-all-classes-in-assembly)

and then use that list to get compare your string with fullName.

Comment: Thank you, Abhay. Well, it's slightly more complicated than simple reflection when it comes to Workflows I guess. However I figured out a way. Will update this thread once I finish testing it.