# How to get a list of classes in a dll without the need for references? c# reflection

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

I want to get the list of classes in an assembly file like below:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(dll);
classesList = a.GetTypes();
```

This assembly uses other references that I haven't them and during getting the classes that exist in them, this error happens:

> Could not load file or assembly 'test.dll Version=1.0.7233.5369, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Actually** I want to skip getting those classes that do not exist in the current assembly and just get its own classes. but `GetTypes()` method doesn't have any skip and it crashes.

Comment: Refre This You get the Ans:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315665/c-list-all-classes-in-assembly

Comment: @Bibin This link that you mentioned refers to a condition that someone wants to get a list of classes in its own assembly, but I want to load an assembly that isn't in my project.

Comment: Check out the next answer after the accepted one in the duplicate, the one with the try/catch, for the way to obtain those types.