# How to register generic services with an interface using reflection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, reflection, .net-6.0

I have multiple services with this pattern, each repository class is using generics for the context and is implementing an interface also with generics:

```cs
public partial interface IUserRepository<TContext>
    : IRepository<TContext, UserRow>
    where TContext : DbContext
{
}

public partial class UserRepository<TContext>
    : RepositoryBase<TContext, UserRow>, IUserRepository<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
{
}
```

I could register my services manually but it's not scaleable as I will have dozens of them:

```cs
services.AddScoped<
    IUserRepository<DatabaseApiDbContext>,
    UserRepository<DatabaseApiDbContext>>();
services.AddScoped<
    IUserRepository<DatabaseApiDbContextSandbox>,
    UserRepository<DatabaseApiDbContextSandbox>>();
```

I think I could simplify the registration? I am not sure that would work, but something like this:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserRepository<>), typeof(UserRepository<>));
```

But that would still require a line of code for each repository.

### Question

I would like to use reflection for registering my repositories. For example:

1. Get all classes in my assembly that are inheriting the generics `RepositoryBase` class (e.g. `XYZRepository<>`)
2. For each of these classes

- Get the type for its corresponding `Repository` interface (e.g. `IXYZRepository<>`)
- Register the `XYZRepository<>` class using the corresponding `IXYZRepository<>` interface

But I am not good enough with reflection to achieve that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: List All Classes in Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315665/c-list-all-classes-in-assembly)

Comment: The thing you show registering with unresolved generics actually works that way. Do you need something beyond that?

Comment: Hi @BurnsBA, only a small part of it. Listing al classes of an assembly is not enough as I have to filter out some that are not repositories. Then I have to find a corresponding interface for each. And the use of generics makes it all more complicated I think

Comment: @Ralf I would need that, but without having to specify it manually with a line of code for every Repository :) I am looking for a loop for registering all my repositories, so when I add more of them, I do not need to add more lines of codes for each new repository

Comment: So besides having an `IUserRepository<T>`, you also have an `ICustomerRepository<T>`, `IOrderRepository<T>`, `ISupplierRepository<T>`, etc? And you want to register them all in one single statement using batch registration? How many repository interfaces are we talking about here?

Comment: _"But I am not good enough with reflection to achieve that."_ - that's not good enough for this site. Please show us your attempts. What's stopping you from writing that code? If it's your own experience in C# Reflection, then I think you already know what you need to do.